# New User has no access to organization page - Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I'm developing app using Liferay Portal 6.2

I have created an organization - Games.

My portal-ext.properties file ->

```
#DISABLING PUBLIC/PRIVATE PAGES FOR EVERY USER
layout.user.private.layouts.enabled=false
layout.user.private.layouts.modifiable=false
layout.user.private.layouts.auto.create=false

layout.user.public.layouts.enabled=false
layout.user.public.layouts.modifiable=false
layout.user.public.layouts.auto.create=false

#DEFAULT LANDING PAGE PATHS
override.default.landing.page.path=true
default.landing.page.path=/group/games/home
custom.landing.page.type=organizationPrivatePage 
auth.forward.by.last.path=true
layout.show.portlet.access.denied=false
auth.login.url=/web/guest/login
```

I'm -

```
- Disabling private and public pages for every user. 
- Defining the landing page for each user after login to the organizations private page. 
- Defining the login url.
```

Now, Whenever, I create a user, the user lands on the page `group/games/home` but it has no access to view the Organizations private page. Am i doing smthing wrong here?

How can I give access to every logged in user to the private page of an organization?

Answer (score 0):

In Control Panel -> Portal Settings, under Default User Associations, you can provide your organization name.
By that every user who register on site will be member of organization and hence user will have access to private pages of organization.